# Is there any merit in doing gelatin fining multiple times?

Tags: techniques, clarity, fining, gelatin

I currently have a Belgian Blond in primary that I'm planning of transferring to a secondary vessel in order to dry hop.

I usually do a gelatin fining when transferring my beer to the bottleing bucket but this time I thought about doing another fining between the primary and the secondary, I'm hoping that this process will decrease the yeast sediment on the bottom of my bottles.

Is there any merit in doing gelatin fining twice (or more for that matter) or that any positive benefit from the process is gained on the first time and any subsequent repeat will achieve nothing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Most of the benefits are achieved the first time.**

Doing a second fining might increase clarity a little bit more, but the difference might be so little that it is not worth the trouble.  Also, if you bottle-condition, you will still end up with yeast in the bottle.

Take a look at the pictures of this test: [Comparing one beer treated with gelatin and one that was not](http://brulosophy.com/2015/01/05/the-gelatin-effect-exbeeriment-results/)

Unless the beer is still really cloudy after the first treatment, I would not do it multiple times.